# How know who access me through Desktop Connection in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, remote, remote-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How reboot computers in a LAN knowing the external IP only?](https://superuser.com/questions/366555/how-reboot-computers-in-a-lan-knowing-the-external-ip-only)

I install team viewer to help remotely the company where I work, but accidentally, I close the team viewer process, and now I need to reboot this computer (there's no one in the company right now, just Monday now) remotely.
The only thing that I could use is the Desktop Remote Connection in Windows 7 (both computer runs it) which I access my computer through this one that I close the team viewer.
If I could find what is the ip I could reboot remotely and then the team viewer could run again normally.

So I wonder, how do I found the ip of this computer that accessed my computer early through Desktop Remote Connection ?

Sorry guys, I know this is messed up, but I need help with this because I'm trying to fix this computer remotely (which I have to do before Monday though).

Comment: Is your home computer the one that you closed the team viewer in?
do you have a team viewer partner list or account?
did you enable a log and thus have the address in program files(or somewhere)

Comment: No @mic84, I close the team viewer in the computer in my company. I have the team viewer partner list in my account, so far, it looks like my partner is online, but I click to connect and nothing. I look through the log file as you said, and I think I could find the ip, but how to reboot this computer through the ip and a port ? By the way, the computer is on a lan, okay ?

Comment: Just look through the windows event log.