# How reboot computers in a LAN knowing the external IP only?

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, reboot

I know the external ip, like the provided by the ISP and the administrator account password.
I need to restart one computer, but I don't know his local ip (given by the router), how can I reboot it ?

Actually, would be better access by the Destop Remote Connection but as I said, I just know the external IP (I'm in my home now, not in the LAN).

Any idea ?

Comment: Actually the router dishes out DHCP IPs that you can see if you can access router via web. Which means that some ports had to be opened up for that.

Comment: Related: [Remotely turning on or rebooting a frozen computer](http://superuser.com/questions/319859/remotely-turning-on-or-rebooting-a-frozen-computer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this should not be construed as advice about ensuring your machine is secure, if you want to access a Windows 7 machine remotely over RDP, you need to port forward TCP port 3389 on your router to the internal address of your W7 machine.

This will allow you to RDP to it from outside your network.  It is worth looking into http://no-ip.org or http://dyndns.org as well to make sure your public IP address has a DNS entry so you don't need to work out the IP each time.

Then to reboot it, start a cmd shell as administrator (Start / Search and type "cmd" / and then right-click, Run as Administrator).  Then type

```
 shutdown /r now
```

Which will reboot your machine "now".

Comment: I'm trying to access the router but unforntunatelly, gives 'This site is running TeamViewer.' because the machine which I wanna to repair has the teamviewer, wich crash so that's why I need to access remotely. Any idea ?

Comment: If you can't get to the router or the machine, then you are probably out of remote options

Answer (score 3):

Can you remote in to another machine on the LAN?  If you can do that, and have administrative privileges on that machine, you might be able to do a `shutdown -r -t 0` (to reboot it) using Sysinternal's [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553).

Please note this will not work on a machine OUTSIDE of the LAN, i.e. if you are on your home internet and the computer is behind a company router.

Comment: Hi @ultrasawblade, I would like to restart this ip :189.1.162.*** how do I use the PsTools to give the command to do it so ?

Comment: `psexec \\189.1.162.*** -u {domain\username} -p {password} C:\windows\system32\shutdown.exe -r -t 0` - enter your domain\username and password at the appropriate points

Comment: I'm trying to reboot my own computer, so I have this ip : 187.115.67.***, my network domain in Windows is : UFSCAR, my computer name is Brainiac, so I'm trying the follow command but not so succesful so far:
C:\PsTools>psexec \\187.115.67.*** -u UFSCAR\Brainiac -p {iamgreyfox} C:\windows\system32\shutdown.exe -r -t 0 - UFSCAR\Valter and iamgreyfox

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this now then I think you are SOL.  However if you can set something up you need to setup a VPN concentrator.  Once you do that you should be able to simply VPN in then call up that machine via it's FQDN (WINS can be problematic of VPN) and then you can admister it all you like.  Further, you could if you just wanna restart it use the remote shutdown command: *shutdown -i* and use the dialogue window or you can use it far more specifically from the command line but the interactive works quite well.